# Change title of Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, titles

I've been searching the web for some time now, trying to find an answer as to why this doesn't work. I'm trying to change the title of the Table of Contents, using the memoir class. Below is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addto\captions\english{%
  \renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

As far as I understand the above will change the title of `\tableofcontents*` from `Contents` to `Table of Contents`. Yet nothing happens. No error or change happens. The output can be seen [here](http://kom.aau.dk/~rbniel/misc/test.pdf). What am I doing wrong? I simply can not find the error.

Version is:

```
rbnielsen@wopr ~/Desktop $ apt-cache show texlive-full
Package: texlive-full
Source: texlive-base
Version: 2012.20120611-5
{snip}
```

Comment: Why not use only `\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}`?

Comment: @Sigur because of `babel`

Comment: Use `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}}`.  `§ 3.1 Basic Macros` of the `babel` manual describes a command in the form of `\captions<lang>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typo: it is called `\captionsenglish` not `\captions\english`